# model a quite complex associtation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to model a quite complex association with ActiveRecord:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # can have one profile_photo
  # can have one cover_photo
end

class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  # can have many photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # can have one user as a profile_photo xor
  # can have one user as a cover_photo xor
  # can have many trips
end
```

Basically, there's a one-to-one relation between the User attributes and the Photo and a many-to-many relation between Trips and Photos. A photo can belong only to a user as a profile_photo xor a cover_photo xor has many sections.

How do I need to put the ActiveRecord's association methods into these classes? Do you suggest a polymorphic association for the Photo model or to use inheritance? Where to put the belongs_to and has_one methods? It sounds more familiar if a photo belongs to a user, but a profile_photo_id and cover_photo_id in the user model might be a better choice.

Comment: You're almost there with your prose descriptions of the associations. Just read the [association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) page and the correspondence with methods should be clear. Then write tests to try it!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I clarified my question.